# Change version of word document programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am dynamically generating a word file, and clicking the link opens the file save dialog and it says the document is a: Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document.

What would I need to do to programmatically generate a 2007, 2010 word document.

Code behind:

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'build the content for the dynamic Word document
    'in HTML alongwith some Office specific style properties. 

    Dim strBody As New System.Text.StringBuilder("")

    strBody.Append("<html " & _
                    "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " & _
                    "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" & _
                    "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" & _
                    "<head><title></title>")

    'The setting specifies document's view after it is downloaded as Print Layout
    'instead of the default Web Layout. For the Header & Footer to be visible,
    'this mode is required.

    strBody.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>" & _
                    "<xml>" & _
                    "<w:WordDocument>" & _
                    "<w:View>Print</w:View>" & _
                    "<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>" & _
                    "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>" & _
                    "</w:WordDocument>" & _
                    "</xml>" & _
                    "<![endif]-->")

    'we can tweak the MsoFooter class that is referenced by the footer, as required

    strBody.Append("<style>" & _
                    "<!-- /* Style Definitions */" & _
                    "p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter" & _
                    "{margin:0in;" & _
                    "margin-bottom:.0001pt;" & _
                    "mso-pagination:widow-orphan;" & _
                    "tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;" & _
                    "font-size:12.0pt;}")

    'Word uses the @page definition to store document layout settings for the entire document.
    'Using @page SectionN, Word applies page formatting to individual HTML elements referenced
    'through the class attribute.

    'mso-footer is the style attribute related to the footer 
    'Refer to the topic "Page Layout and Section Breaks" & "Headers and Footers" in the 

    'Office XML & HTML Reference for detailed info.

    strBody.Append("@page Section1" & _
                    "   {size:8.5in 11.0in; " & _
                    "   margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in ; " & _
                    "   mso-header-margin:.5in; " & _
                    "   mso-footer: f1;" & _
                    "   mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;}" & _
                    " div.Section1" & _
                    "   {page:Section1;}" & _
                    "-->" & _
                    "</style></head>")

    strBody.Append("<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>" & _
                    "<div class=Section1>" & _
                    "<h1>A dynamically generated document with Footer</h1>" & _
                    "<p style='color:red'><I> This doc was generated on " & _
                    DateTime.Now & "</I></p><hr>")

    'We are building up a big string here so that the generated doc runs into multiple pages.

    For counter As Integer = 1 To 50
        strBody.Append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, " & _
                        "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
    Next

    strBody.Append("</div>")

    'Word marks and stores information for simple fields by means of the Span element with the 
    'mso-field-code style. Refer to the topic "Fields" in the Office XML & HTML Reference

    strBody.Append("<div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>" & _
                    " <p class=MsoFooter>" & _
                    " <span style='mso-tab-count:2'></span><span style='mso-field-code:"" PAGE ""'></span>" & _
                    " </p></div>" & _
                    "</body></html>")

    'Force this content to be downloaded 
    'as a Word document with the name of your choice

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword")
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", _
                            "attachment; filename=myword.doc")
    Response.Write(strBody)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document is neither a 97 - 2003 nor a 2007 - 2010 document; it's a Word HTML document.

The save dialog says `Word 97 - 2003 Document` because you're sending an incorrect extension.
Changing the extension (in the `Content Disposition` header) to `.docx` will make the save dialog say `Word Document`, but will not make the document any more valid.  (and will probably make Word more likely to show a warning)

You need to generate an OpenXML package, not Word HTML.
You can use Microsoft's [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) to do this.
Note that this will require a complete rewrite of your method.